# Rewriting gates such as XOR into three basic gates?

Tags: logic, xor

How would I rewrite an XOR gate into the three basic logic gates (AND, OR, NOT). To be more specific, I have to write it in such a way with 2 NOT gates, 2 OR gates, and 1 AND gate. I also have to do it with 1 OR gate, 2 AND gates, and 1 NOT gate.

I'm not looking for just the answer, I'm looking for a way to come up with the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Try writing XOR in conjunctive or disjunctive normal form.

Comment: You do it in the same way you'd implement any function using some set of gates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  $a \oplus b = \neg \big( (a \land b) \lor (\neg a \land \neg b)\big)$  (you can't have both true and you can't have both false).  Using De Morgan's, you should be able to break up the negation and the main $\lor$.

Comment: Thanks, I did De Morgan's law multiple times and I got the answer to both parts!